# What is the multiplicative order of $1+\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, integral-domain

Actually I am in the context of *Contemporary Algebra* by Gallian, where there is topic of divisibility in integral domains, where there is inverse of $1+\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$. I understand and know how to find inverse of $1+\sqrt{2}$, but this question after asked what is multiplicative order of $1+\sqrt{2}$? I want to know what is multiplicative order of $1+\sqrt{2}$?

I am not sure what is multiplicative order.

Answer (score 4):

By definition the multiplicative order of an element $x$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ (if it exists) such that $x^n=e$, where $e$ is the identity element of the set given. If no such $n$ exists then the order is said to be infinite.

In your case you should ask, is there a positive integer $n$ such that
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^n=1.$$

As you can see the left side is $>1$ so such a $n$ cannot exist. Thus the multiplicative order should be infinite.

Comment: can you please tell me in context of "Find the inverse of 1+squrt(2) in z[sqrt(2)]. What is the multiplicative order of 1+sqrt(2)?" means in z[squrt(2)]. Is your answer remain same for my conidtion?  please help in my context of z[sqrt(2])

Comment: @SandipPatel I think you are confusing between two different concepts of order and inverse. For example in reals every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse but except for $\pm 1$, everything else has infinite order.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative order of $a=\sqrt{2}+1$ is $\infty$. This can be easily shown using the fact that the group of units of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ can be embedded (trivially by inclusion) in the multiplicative group $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. So
$$a < a^2 < a^3 < \dots$$
as you can see, you can never have that $a^k=1$ for $k>0$. So all powers of $a$ are distinct.

Comment: You're missing a non-trivial or an $\ne 1$ somewhere.

Comment: Even the group $\;\{\,\pm1\,\}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \neq \{\pm1\}$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$, and yet $1$ has order $1$, while $-1$ has order $2$. You use in your first paragraph (without saying it) that $a > 1 > 0$.

Comment: OK: my last comment was simply a heuristic comment. I deleted it since it was not so precise.

Comment: no. It is in z[sqrt(2)].